# How to save E-mails from Comment

Tags: php, html

Source Code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

$content = "";

if(file_exists("messages.inc.html"))
   $content = file_get_contents("messages.inc.html");

if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
  $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $content .=  "\n<b>From:</b> " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . 
               " <b>eMail:</b> " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . 
               " <b>at:</b> $time<br><br>" .
  htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']) . <"hr">;

  file_put_contents("messages.inc.html", $content);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Message schreiben</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Messages</h1>
    <h2>Insert new Message:</h2>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>E-Mail: <br><input type="text" name="email"><br></label>
        <label> Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"><br></label>
        <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="45" rows="6" name="text">    
        </textarea><br></label>
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="post">
    </form>

<?php
    if (strlen($content))
       echo $content;
    else
     echo "<h2>No Messages availabe</h2>";
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When someone will write his E-mail in the comment, I dont want it to be displayed alongside comment later. Instead, I want to save the email to my `**messages.inc.html**` file.

How can i do it? Can anyone please help me, Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your question or issue is.

Comment: thanks for your answer , i have a File , messages.inc.html , when someone write his  Comment and name  , save this information to this File , but the E-mail not ....

Comment: You have a field `name="text"` with the message, but you don't do anything with it. You need to save the value just like the other two variables.

Comment: @ Progman , can you please explain how to do it . I am only two Months with html and only 10 days with PHP... , Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People had help me and with a new Code , i can to do it....

```
<!dictop html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
        <label>E-Mail: *<br><input placeholder="my e-mail" type="text" name="email"><br></label>
     <br>
        <label> Name: *<br><input placeholder="my name" type="text" name="name">  

  <br></label>
     <br>
        <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="45" rows="6" name="text"></textarea>

  <br></label>
     <p>
        <input  type="submit" name="post" value="POST COMMENT" id="comment">
     </p>
     <br>
     <h1>Comments</h1>
     <br>


</form>



<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message =  $_POST['text'];
$file = "test.txt";

if(isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message)){
    $data = array("name" => $name, "email" => $email, "message" => $message);
    $data = serialize($data);
    file_put_contents($file, $data . "\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
}

$messages = file($file);

foreach ($messages as $line) {
    $data = unserialize($line);
    echo "<b>" . "From:" . "</b>" . " " . $data["name"] . " ";
    echo "<b>" . "at:" . "</b>" . " " . $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) . "<br><br>";
    echo $data["message"] . "<br><br>";
    echo "<hr>";

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now  , i have how i will :

**From:** me **at:** 07/07/2018 11:33:43 am

The E-mail is not displayed alongside comment , and it is to save on  test.txt file... .